# Error using method from another class

Tags: java, swing

I think this might be a scope issue but it's been bugging me for a while. Whenever I try to add ReplayData to the frame I recieve a null pointer  error, nor can I use my add data method without it throwing a null pointer error. p.Setx is defintely setting the right values, but once it hits "replaydata.add" an error gets thrown and the loop cannot continue.

```
    public ReplayData replayData;

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1920, 1080);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // ERROR HERE WHEN ADDING TO FRAME, APPLICATION RUNS FINE IF COMMENTED
    //frame.add(replayData); // Add replay data to jframe

    JButton button_KMeans = new JButton("View K-Means");
    button_KMeans.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            kMeans.initialize();
            kMeans.kMeanCluster();
            kMeans.PrintResults();

            //for (Point p : kMeans.getPoints() )

            Point temp = new Point();
            for (int i = 0; i < kMeans.TOTAL_DATA; i++)
            {           
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),kMeans.TOTAL_DATA, "Dialog",
                //        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);;
                p.setX((int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeX());
                p.setY((int)TrackerData.getRecordNumber(i).getEyeY());

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),p.getX(), "Dialog",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),p.getY(), "Dialog",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                // GET ERROR HERE when adding these points to replayData. everything look fine in that class unless i'm missing something
                // java.lang.NullPointerException at MainWindow$3.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:189)
                replayData.addPoint(p); // Add points to JPanel
            }
            //replayData.draw();  
        }
    });
```

That is my button class, I get errors whenever I try to add data using my replaydata class

Heres the other 2 ReplayData +  DataPoint class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ReplayData extends JPanel {

public ArrayList<DataPoint> points;

// Initialise records
public ReplayData()
{
    points = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
}

public void ReplaceData() {
    points = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
}

public void addPoint(DataPoint point) {
    points.add(point);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (DataPoint p : points) 
        g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 2, 2);
}

public void draw() {
    repaint();
}
```

}

public class DataPoint{

```
public DataPoint(int X, int Y)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

int x,y;
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated.

Copy of my project if anyone wants to open it on eclipse (I've included the .csv you will need to get it working aswell in the zip) : http://www.filedropper.com/eyetrackeranalysis_1

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: This by the way is not recommended: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: I'm getting null pointer error. That code was automated for me when using the swing editor in eclipse, If this is something to be wary of thanks for the advice I will remove it and study the effects.

Heres a screenshot of my console when I compile for you http://tinypic.com/r/dlnic1/8

Answer (score 2):

You declare the variable:

```
public ReplayData replayData;
```

but never initialize it. Your line above is equivalent to this:

```
public ReplayData replayData = null;
```

You need to assign an object to the variable for it to be non-null.

```
public ReplayData replayData = new ReplayData();
```

---

More importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). **You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully**, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Wow i'm really kicking myself over that one thanks for pointing that one out! I don't suppose you could help me with my GUI, the paint method is still not doing anything when I call it. I've tried adding a message box pop-up when paint is entered but I get nothing show up!

Comment: @does_not_compute: My guess - you may be shooting yourself in the foot with your use of `null` layouts. If you're adding the ReplayData without setting its bounds, it will be 0x0 size. But don't guess, add a Border to it and see what it's size looks like. My main rec though is to avoid `null` layouts like the plague, and not just because it labels your GUI as a newbie GUI, but because they are so difficult to debug and enhance.

Comment: Cheers i've never been so happy to see some dots appear on the screen. Not quite sure how I fixed it though don't think the setbounds is actually restricting where the data is being draw at a minute, maybe getting rid of the null saved me, thanks again for the advice. Heres a picture at the minute of what i;ve got. I would like the screen to refresh whenever I click + / - on the clusters but can't seem to get it working. I've tried removing from the frame + re-adding but that isn't doing much. The new centroids are definitely being re-calculated